# What does it mean when the map $u \mapsto \lVert u \rVert$ is continuous with respect to the norm $\lVert u \rVert_1$

Tags: linear-algebra, continuity, normed-spaces

> Given any norm $\lVert \, \rVert$ on a vector space of dimension $n$, for any basis $(e_1, \dots, e_n)$ of E, observe that for any vector $x=x_1 e_1 + \dots x_n e_n$, we have
>   $$\lVert x \rVert = \lVert x_1 e_1 + \dots x_n e_n \rVert \leq C \lVert x \rVert_1\, , $$
>   with $C=\max_{1\leq i \leq n} \lVert e_i \rVert$ and
>   $$\lVert x \rVert_1 = \lVert x_1e_1+\dots +x_ne_n \rVert = \lvert x_1 \rvert + \dots + \lvert x_n \rvert$$
>   The above implies that
>   $$\lvert \lVert u \rVert - \lVert v \rVert \rvert \leq \lVert u - v \rVert \leq C \lVert u-v \rVert_1 \, ,$$ 
>   which means that **the map $u \mapsto \lVert u \rVert$ is continuous with respect to the norm $\lVert \, \rVert_1$**

I think I have the intuition on how the inequality leads to the continuity, but need some further guidance on that. I used the $\epsilon - \delta$ definition of continuity and let $f(u)=\lVert u \rVert$ and $\delta = \epsilon /C$, so that when $\lvert u - v \rvert \leq \delta$, we will have $\lVert u - v \rVert \leq \epsilon$ and thereby the continuity.

What confused me is the last sentence, which says **the map $u \mapsto \lVert u \rVert$ is continuous with respect to the norm $\lVert \, \rVert_1$**. What does it mean when it says "continuous with respect to the p-norm"?

Comment: Any two norm $||•||_1,||•||_2$ on a finite dimensional vector space is comparable i.e. we have positive numbers $a,b$ such that $||•||_1≤a||•||_2$ and $||•||_2≤b||•||_1$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the $\varepsilon-\delta$ notation, this means: at any $u$, for every $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists some $\delta(\varepsilon) > 0$, such that whenever $\|v-u\|_1 \le \delta$ (note here is the $1$-norm), we have $|(\|u\|-\|v\|)| \le \varepsilon$. (here is the difference of your function value, i.e., in terms of $\|\cdot\|$.)

Comment: Then is the $\epsilon - \delta$ definition only valid for 1-norm?

Comment: I think I get it....So from @UserS comment, if we can prove that the map $u \mapsto \lVert u \rVert$ is continuous with respect to 1-norm, then from the equivalence of norm, we can show that the map $u \mapsto \lVert u \rVert$ is continuous with respect to any p-norm.